# Clear data from an ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have two ng-grids on a page, a textbox, an add button and an apply button. When the page loads, options fill the first ng-grid. The second grid remains empty. The user clicks an option from the first grid, enters info into the text box and then clicks the add button. The info the user enters is then displayed in the second grid. When the user clicks apply the info is saved in the db. 
When the user clicks another option in the first grid I need the info that was previously entered to be cleared. Anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to assign [] to the variable in your model that the grid is bound to.

Comment: Thanks! I did try that. When I step through the code I see that there is no longer any data in the vm.gridOptions however the grid doesn't clear on the page.

Comment: Sorry! That was for the grid. I did what was suggested for the model and it worked. Thanks!